# Notification not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications

In a class when a method is performed, I have put this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"locationFromZipFound" object:array];
```

and in the class that I wish to recieve the notification I have this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(getZipLocation:) 
                                             name:@"locationFromZipFound" 
                                           object:nil];
```

The problem is, this is never called:

```
-(void)getZipLocation:(NSNotification *)notification; {
NSLog(@"Zip received and put into array!");
NSArray *location = [notification object];
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy and pasted your code and it works great for me.
I put the `postNotification` on a Button and the `addObserver` on `viewDidAppear:animated`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I got it working by registering for notifications in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind!  I was trying to register for notifications in a method, and it seemed like it didn't like that.  I just registered for notifications in `viewDidLoad` and all seems to be well!

Comment: Be sure that you are OK having that method called multiple times, as every time viewDidLoad is called it will register again...  that happens when you get a memory warning with that view offscreen, then it will dump the view and re-load it when you go back to the screen.

Comment: @Kendall Good point!  Any reason why it doesn't seem to be registering for notifications if I put it in method?

Comment: That depends on which method you are putting it in, it could be the notification fires before the class tries to register.  There's nothing wrong with putting it in viewDidLoad, just be aware it might get called more than once.